# How to insert data to mysql database that synchronously update the JTable in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jtable

[image]

I get data to above GUI JTable in below table

```
CREATE TABLE store_room(
store_id int,
store_capacity int
);
```

when I insert new record to this sql table it must immediately update the jtable synchronously
can anyone tell how to do it ?

note:- question is not clear, I will explain  little bit

my insert data GUI is something like this
[image]

my class structure is as below

I create a java bean class to represent a tuple of a table.

```
public class StoreRoom{
private int storeId;
private int storeCapacity;

    public int getSstoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(int storeId) {
        this.storeRoomId = storeId;
    }
```

//  getter setter methods
//

```
}
```

to represent a table behavior I create a class called StoreRoomData as below

```
public class  StoreRoomData {

    public static void insert(StoreRoom bean){
     // some code to insert like below
String sql="INSERT INTO StoreRoom(store_id ,store_capacity )"+
                "values(?,?);";
    ResultSet keys=null;
    try (
            Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
         ){
        stmt.setInt(1, bean.getSstoreId());  
        stmt.setInt(2, bean.getSstoreCapacity());  



        int affacted = stmt.executeUpdate();
}

}
```

in a form  I create a bean object and calling setMethods all the GUI inputs set to the bean object and pass it to insert method which as StoreRoomData class as beleow

```
StoreRoom bean = new StoreRoom();

    bean.setStoreId(Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText()));



StoreRoomData.insert(bean);
```

I hope this will clear

Comment: whats your environment? who call the update on database? same java-application or someone else?

Comment: data base update with anther GUI in java.

Comment: you should try to hook the insert-process. Is it the same program, can your insert program call functions on the GUI? if so, you should try the Observer-Pattern of @user3413094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not very clear. How do you insert the new record? You have a java method for that?

If so you can implement the [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) . Through this pattern you can define an observer object that gets notified when a new record is inserted. Your code would look like this

```
public interface DBObserver{
      public void notifyNewRecordInserted();
}

public class MyTable extends JTable implements DBOserver{
       public void notifyNewRecordInserted(){
              this.refresh();
       }

       public void refresh(){
            //some code to refresh the table
       }
}

public class DBManager(){
     private List<DBObserver> observers;

     public void addObserver(DBObserver observer){
         this.observers.add(observer);
     }


     public DBObserver  removeObserver(DBObserver observer){
         this.observers.remove(observer);
         return observer;
     }

     public void insert(Record record){
           //some code to insert the new record

           //notify observers
           this.notifyObservers();
     }


     private void notifyObservers(){
        for(DBObserver observer: this.observers){
               observer.notifyNewRecordInserted();
        }
     }
}
```

This way you can update automatically every component that needs to be updated when a new record is inserted even if you don't know what that component may be when you first develop your solution.

In other words now you know that you want to update your table, but in the future you may notice that you want to update another table too whenever new records are inserted.

All you have to do is implement the DBObserver interface in your new class and make objects of that class register themselves by calling addObserver().

The notifyObservers method notifies all registered observers. The method doesn't even have to know what that components are.

---

Comment: Im new to java programming. can you revise my question and something add to your answer ? Im trying to understand your answer but I have no good idea about interfaces

Comment: what kind of code is here //some code to refresh the table

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow and i hadn't noticed you questions.
Interfaces are let's say java elements that you can define. An interface defines methods without giving a concrete implementation. Later you can define a class that states that implements these methods using a syntax like 'class A implements I'. Now you must implement all the methods that are defined in I. 

Now why is this useful?

This is useful because you can write code that uses the interface I. If you add implement I in a different way later, there will be no need to change anything else in your code.

Comment: About the code that you should add there it depends on the application you're developing. You should query your database to get the results that contain the newly inserted records and display these records at you table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Thread, whith inifinite while loop, you check your database , if there is a new record inserted, get it & insert it into Jtable.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
             while(true){
                       result = query.execute("select .....");    // check DB
                       if(newRecord){   // check if there is a new record 
                               // get the new record
                               //  insert it into Jtable
                       }
                       sleep(100) // to avoid consecutive acces to your DB
                      }
             }
}
```

Comment: how to find new record here in if clause ?

Answer (score 1):

I am am understanding this correctly you are saying you have a separate add data window/place to add data in which you input something and then submit it to the database. If this is correct you can do 1 of 2 things,

1. When you click submit your function triggers both a database insert and an addition to the data model that table is bound to. This can be done for a single user situation.
2. You can only update the database and have the table auto-refresh (using a thread) which will constantly pull data from the database when new things appear. If you have a multiple users situation this is the way to go.